# Accidentally used a fake name for eBay purchase

Tags: ebay

I put a fake name on eBay and bought stuff. However, I recently purchased a tablet screen, and they require me to fetch it in the post office. I realized that they had sent me the package with the fake name.  And I checked on the eBay website that fake name is not allowed. So then I won't get the package?  I didn't know that I should use the real name as my previous purchase was small enough to fit in my mailbox, and I didn't have to fetch it myself in the post office.

So what now?

Answer (score -2):

1. Why use a fake name when buying stuff for yourself, unless it is somewhat shady or illegal?
2. Don’t pick it up from the post office (as you already can’t), have them return it to the seller; then change your name on eBay to your real name and have the seller resend it to your correct name. Pay the seller the additional cost of resending the package.
3. If you want to stay anonymous when ordering stuff online get a postbox at your local post office; it comes with a cost though.

Comment: 1. We teach children these days not to give out real personal details online. All the accounts my son has are in a variety of fake names. I can easily see him sticking with this policy in the future for the privacy reasons. 2. Do you know if the Post Office will actually require ID? I would turn up, say “Hello, I’m Fakey McFakename, here to collect my package” and if they ask for ID then I’d provide proof of address.

Comment: @Vicky - that's pretty much an answer. And exactly what I do. I don't need to register "JoeTaxpayer" with my local post office, any mail just comes to my address, and at pick up time, say for an oversized package, I justy show my ID. This question might be closed as off topic, but yours is a good answer.

Comment: @Vicky I am not sure I follow that need for privacy when purchasing stuff online, but fair enough. Regarding the fake name it surely depends on OPs location; where I live you cannot collect anything from the post office without valid ID (and if not addressed to you, you need to provide a power of attorney issued by the recipient with that persons ID and signature) - I cant even pick up my wife’s packages at the post office even thou we share the same address without her providing me with a power of attorney.

Comment: Downvoters, do you have any alternative? (+1)  I might tweak 2) to say "explain to the seller, and expect to pay a second lot of postage"